# Inserted image is at the top of the page

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm trying to insert an image into my paper however it's being inserted at the very top and not where I want it, my .tex file looks something like this:

```
% Bunch of text here,
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/image.jpg}
\caption{aaa}
\end{figure}
% More text after
```

Comment: Use \begin{figure}[!h] ... \end{figure}

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of figure environment, try without using figure.